# How to make floating scrollbar?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a table which uses scrollbar-x and y.

As you can see scrollbar-y disappears when I move scrollbar-x

I want scrollbar-y to keep appears.

I've tried  `position: fixed or sticky`

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  position: fixed or sticky
}
```

But it doesn't seem to the solution for it. Any Ideas?

*Note scrollbar-x and scrollbar-y are located different tag

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "floating scrollbar"?